# C# Можно ли в csproj файле библиотеки классов создать два одинаковых dll с разным названием?

Tags: c#, dll, csproj

К сожалению, не смог найти ответ на свой вопрос на просторах интернетах (хотя единожды встречал формулировку, что на выходе csproj не создает более одного файла, но конкретики не нашёл по этому утверждению). Поэтому вот решил спросить тут.
Ситуация следующая: есть проект, в нем несколько решений для различных плагинов. И так получается, что в установщике хотелось бы добиться, чтобы два проекта получали по одному пути файлы dll, а третий к аналогичным dll файлам по другому пути (это связано с тем, что иначе библиотеки начинают перекрывать друг друга в системе, для которой как раз пишутся плагины, что приводит к неожиданным последствиям). Решение напросилось самое простое -- просто в csproj файле на выход поставить два файла, но с разным наименованием. Можете что-нибудь посоветовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать MsBuild

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)..\..\Lib\*.dll" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)Debug\bin" SkipUnchangedFiles="false" />
  <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)..\..\Lib\*.dll" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)Release\bin" SkipUnchangedFiles="false" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Кажется, это действительно решает мою проблему. Я Вам очень благодарен.